# java selenium - Nav to a page number not shown on a Paginated Table

Tags: java, selenium, pagination

**Background**

I have a Selenium script in java that performs a search and the result are in a paginated table. The table nav at the bottom is:

[‹‹ First]  [‹ Prev]  [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]  [Next ›]  [Last ››]

In some cases, my search will return 100s of thousands of records which would give me 10s of thousands of pages.

**Issue**

My Issue is, when I run the script, if it stops or crashes in the middle for what ever reason. The next time I run the script, it has to go through all the pages that I had previously searched, to get back to where it left off. So my script will look at row 'X' and see if I already looked at that record, skip it if I checked in a previous run or do what it needs to if I had not checked it. After all rows of page number 'Y' are complete, go to the next page. This takes too long when I need to go all the way back to a page that's a high number.

Url does not have any page info in it and does not change. Stays at ....resultTable.html.

The page does not have a "Go to Page: [ ]" input field to jump to a page. And, we cannot add it.

**Solution?**

I was thinking, if there is a way I can just navigate to a requested page, maybe with javascript? Because the table's navigation bar does not allow you to jump to a page. I would perform my search and on page 1 I would check what ever page my last run got to and navigate to that page. That way my script does not need to go through every page 1 by 1, checking each row if that is a record I already checked.... (I am technicaly weak in this area, need your help )

This is the onClick="" code on the table nav:

```
<a href="#" 
   onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(
      document.getElementById('idHere'), 
      {'j_idt##:#:j_idt##':'j_idt##:#:j_idt##', 
      'pageIndex':'',
      'moveToPageNum':'##'},
      '');return false"
>##</a>
```

I wonder if I can just send javaScript code with the requested page I need in the `'moveToPageNum':'##'` section?

In my script, at some point I use `JavascriptExecutor` to perform a task, maybe I can use it for the purposes described above? Example of how I use it in a different place in my script:

```
public static void openNewTab(WebDriver driver, String url) { 
   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('" + url + " ','_blank');");
   changeTab(driver, url);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid clicking on `Next ›`?

Comment: @Alex adding html or url is better.

Comment: If I click Next, I have to go through everypage, and when I have thousands of pages, it will take to long to wait for each one to load... the url does not have a page number in it. It just says, ....resultsTable.html

Comment: I added some more text to the "Solutions?" part of the question above 

Comment: @DebanjanB and @ ewwink Thanks for the help. It worked with executing javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, After a lot of editing my question, and I'm sure people opening the question and being like "I have to read all this...". I got it, sorry .

I made a method that executes java script:

```
public static void goToPage(WebDriver driver, int page) {

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript("mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('idHere'),"
                           + "{'j_idt##:#:j_idt##':'j_idt##:#:j_idt##','pageIndex':'',"
                           + "'moveToPageNum':'" + page + "'}," + "'');return false");
}
```